# DateCreated Property Is Wrong

Tags: c#, properties, uwp, storagefolder

I'm getting a list of album folders in the user's music library like this:

```
var _folderList = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);
```

However, when I try to get the `DateCreated` prop on each folder most of them are showing "12/31/1600 7:00:00 PM" which is, of course, quite wrong. The weird thing is that if I use Windows Explorer to go look at the properties of the folders they show entirely different-- and correct-- values. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: @Jonesopolis Ah! That kinda helped... I checked and, sure enough, the `Path` property is empty on the folders that aren't working. *Why* I have no idea. But I think you've put me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: sure thing, glad it helped.